# Is it normal for my kittens hair to fall out? Will bathing or diet change help?

Tags: cats, health

When I pick up my kitten, some hair sheds (no bald spots) - is this normal?

What is a good diet choice for a 3 month old kitten that may help it's shedding? Should he be bathed?

Comment: Do you mean shedding hair or has visible bald spots?

Comment: when we pick him up , we see broken hair on our hands ? is it normal ? should we avoid picking him up

Comment: Do you have any pic by chance? Trying to figure out if it's drastic hair loss/shedding, clumps of fur at a time, patchiness without baldness or normal shedding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hair loss** – It depends on where on the body the hair is missing. Is she itchy? Common causes in kittens are parasites, fungi, food/flea/environmental allergies. A vet will be able to suggest which is most likely, perform tests, and initiate treatment. Flea control would be my starting point in the absence of any other information. Avoid home remedies. Your kitten is losing hair for a reason, and it is important to identify the reason at this point before the problem worsens.

**Diet** – A 3 month old kitten needs a high quality kitten food that contains enough calories and nutrients for rapid growth. There are many different brands that would be good choices, Science Diet kitten food would be my top recommendation. Wet or dry food is fine. Homemade diets are not ideal because you cannot be sure what nutrients the kitten is receiving.

**Baths** – Does your kitten *need* a bath? A kitten shouldn't really need a bath unless they got into something messy and couldn't clean it off themselves. At this stage they should be grooming themselves. Give baths if needed but let the kitten do the work most of the time.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't sound like a skin condition. It sounds more like a normal in-door cat. Our cat sheds his fur all year round. If you don't brush him regularly, you will end up with hair everywhere.

Nevertheless, I would get him to a vet to make sure it's not pathogenic or allergic.

Regarding food, I have to agree with Harry V. Get him some good store brand food. I have been feeding expensive food to my cat since we found him and he's been the healthiest little bugger.

As for baths, I advice against it unless it hasn't learned how to clean itself from its mother. If you want to get rid of dead fur, **brush** it, don't wash it. It's better he learned to accept the brush from early on or it will be hard later.

Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: we are feeding ROYAL CANIN brand (persian kitten specific because we have persian kitten), is it fine ?

Comment: Royal Canin breed specific is usually a great food, unless there's something in it your cat has an allergy to. If it's a "kitten" not a cat, you should have some booster/ shot and or de-worming visits coming up possibly? Wondering if it's worth asking the vet if you'll be seeing him soon anyways.

Comment: That's actually excellent, I've been using the same. Once we had him fixed, I switched to the sterilized type and he hasn't gained a single pound after the operation. I wanted to avoid recommending a brand but 100% good one.

Comment: @ChristyB. I think i should change vet asap, he suggests me to give boiled chicken yogurt rice boiled egg to my kitten, as soon as i started using stackexchange things were opposite.

Comment: Strange, did he have an issue with the Royal Canin? Is it a "kitten" formula?  Did your  little one have any other issues besides the hair? I'm curious why he'd want your kitty on a different diet, if he finds an issue with the Royal Canin

Comment: @Christy B. I would assume that the vet advised that diet before he OP posted here. Boiled chicken is excellent for cats of all ages. When our old outside cat was attacked and we were nurturing him back to health, the vet advised boiled chicken and I think that's what saved him.